# I have tried everything on stackoverflow but nothing worked, Autofill by google chrome is really messing up with my theme, what should i do?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have created a template with a great css, all i need to have is no background-color means transparent background with white font color. but google chrome is messing with my theme. What should I do?

I have tried every single thing that exist on the internet nothing worked for me. Is there any other suggestions?
Here is the one of things I tried.

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: In the Firefox browsers internal *forms.css*  is commented that they use a `background-image` as it is *less likely to be overridden by the page.* I'd suggest try working around your problem with an `:autofill { background-image: linear-gradient(...single color...) !important; }`. Maybe add a `filter: invert(100%)` to get `color: white`. When you do, use the complementary color of the color used in the linear gradient as that too gets inverted. Using complement corrects the inversion. Just a thought, not tested... And explain in the CSS why you use the workaround. Over time ppl tend to forget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change input box styles as well as text styles inside `input` box:

Here you can use any color e.g. `white`, `#DDD, rgba(102, 163, 177, 0.45)`.

But `transparent` won't work here.

```css
/* Change the white to any color */
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
}
```

Additionally, you can use this to change the text color:

```css
/*Change text in autofill textbox*/
input:-webkit-autofill{
    -webkit-text-fill-color: yellow !important;
}
```

**Advice:** Don't use an excessive blur radius in the hundreds or thousands. This has no benefit and might put processor load on weaker mobile devices. (Also true for actual, outside shadows). For a normal input box of 20px height, 30px ‘blur radius’ will perfectly cover it.

Comment: It didn't work I have already tried it, as It was suggested by someone else too on stackoverflow. I didn't work for me